# SlideDown() not working after slick carousel chage breakpoint

Tags: javascript

I have accordion combination: tabs is slider (I use slick carousel with set break point). It work fine, until I resize window over break point, it not until working.

This is my site:

http://geeman-2.myshopify.com/ 
(New arrivals section)

And this my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('.sub-slider').slick({
    dots: false,
    infinite: true,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 3000,
    speed: 300,
    slidesToShow: 6,
    slidesToScroll: 6,
    responsive: [
      {
        breakpoint: 1208,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 4,
          slidesToScroll: 4
        }
      },
      {
        breakpoint: 798,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 2,
          slidesToScroll: 2
        }
      },
      {
        breakpoint: 480,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 1,
          slidesToScroll: 1
        }
      }
    ]
  });

  var panelHandle;
  $('.btn-on').on('click', function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        handle = $this.data('handle');
    panelHandle = handle;

    $('#' + handle).slideDown('slow');
    $('.triangle-' + handle).slideDown('slow');

    $('.' + handle).slick({
      dots: false,
      infinite: true,

      speed: 300,
      arrows: false,
      slidesToShow: 4,
      slidesToScroll: 4,
      responsive: [
      {
        breakpoint: 798,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 2,
          slidesToScroll: 2
        }
      },
      {
        breakpoint: 480,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 1,
          slidesToScroll: 1
        }
      }
      ]
    });   
  });

  $('.btn-close').on('click', function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        handle = $this.data('handle');
    $('#' + handle).slideUp(1000);
    $('.triangle-' + handle).slideUp(1000);
  });

  });
```

I hope everyone help me solve it! 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the `$('.slick-carousel-responsive').resize();` trick found here? https://github.com/jellekralt/Responsive-Tabs/issues/52 - adding it to my resize event fixed a similar issue for me!